# Override contacts controller

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to override contacts controller, but request in not coming in my module postAction.
**1-config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> <config>    <frontend>
         <routers>
            <contacts>
                 <args>
                     <modules>
                         <Xyz_Contacts before="Mage_Contacts">Xyz_Contacts</Xyz_Contacts>
                    </modules>
                 </args>
            </contacts>
         </routers>
     </frontend> </config>
```

**2-controllers**

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Contacts').DS.'IndexController.php');

    class Xyz_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
    {
     public function postAction()
        {
            die('coming');
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ( $post ) {
                $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
                /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
                $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
                try {
                    $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                    $postObject->setData($post);

                    $error = false;                

                    if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                        $error = true;
                    }

                    if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                        $error = true;
                    }

                    if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                        $error = true;
                    }


                    if ($error) {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                    $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                    /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                    $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                        ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                        ->sendTransactional(
                            Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                            Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                            //Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom2/email'),
                            Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                            null,
                            array('data' => $postObject)
                        );


                    if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }


                    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                    return;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);



                    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    return;
                }

            } else {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
        }

    }
```

**3- Module file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Xyz_Contacts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Xyz_Contacts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

how can i check that my module has overwritten the core contacts controller method.I just want to check the post request is coming to my controller so that i can work on further logic.

Comment: I was posting an answer before you added the require part, is it still not working?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue with this same controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one part in the controller class, you need to require the original controller you want to override:

`require_once 'Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php');`

Take a look [HERE](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) for a step by step guide